# Quarkus Gradle multimodule projects with configuration cache enabled

Tags: gradle, quarkus

how to enable [gradle configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html) in a Quarkus multi-module projects? We are using [jandex](https://github.com/kordamp/jandex-gradle-plugin) for indexing, [as suggested by Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling#multi-module-gradle). However it seems that jandex doesn't support this feature since I am getting this error

```
- Task `:base:jandex` of type `org.kordamp.gradle.plugin.jandex.tasks.JandexTask`: cannot serialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultUnlockedConfiguration', a subtype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
```

I am wondering how are you guys handling this in your multi-module Quarkus project

UPDATE

The answer is to change the gradle plugin. Just use [this one](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.vlsi.jandex) instead